# Creación de llaves foráneas LARAVEL

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tengo una consulta.

se bien que cuando se deben de hacer las relaciones o agregando sus llaves foráneas a cada tabla, según el amerita el caso. debo de crearlas en orden según las fechas y de ahí se crean  tablas etc.

pero por ej. Tengo todas estas tablas.

Usuarios, Publicaciones, Categorias, Etiquetas, Comentarios, Likes,
Ventas etc.

---

### Aveces se me suele pasar porque primero creó la tabla ventas y después la de categorías.

llevando eso a que ocurre un error, porque está buscando la tabla categorías cuando aún no existe. 
¿Hay alguna forma de Que esto se pueda omitir?  ya ignorando el orden en que he creado las tablas en sus respectivas fechas?

no hay alguna forma de poder, Decir primero creo la tabla y despues hago su relación, No sé alguna u otra funcion deba de agregar?

```html
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ventas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('nombre',130);
            $table->text('descripcion');
            $table->string('fileUrl');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('categoria_id')->unsigned();


            $table->foreign('usuario_id') 
            ->references('id')
            ->on('usuarios')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('categoria_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categorias')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');


            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no se puede alterar el orden en que se ejecutan las migraciones, lo que puedes hacer es quitar la foreign key de la migración ventas y agregarla en otra migración al final, así cuando se cree ésta no tendrás el problema de que aún no existe categorias.

quedaría de ésta forma la nueva migración:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('ventas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('categoria_id')->after('user_id');

            $table->foreign('categoria_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categorias')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Comment: No es necesario crear la columna 'categoria_id', podés agregar solo las foreigns. Mientras no esté definida la relación, no vas a tener problemas al migrar las tablas y las foreigns quedan al final.  Pero también podrías cambiar los nombres de los archivos de migracion para que queden en orden.